# How can I get headphone output from Edifier R1280T speaker

Tags: audio, speakers, headphones

I have Edifier R1280T speaker for my PC. The sound quality is great but it does not have a headphone jack which makes it difficult to use at nights.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to manually add an insert a headphone jack or use existing output to connect a headphone?

The manual can be found [here](https://cdn.ventmere.com/edifier-dev/uploads/2016-06/R1280T-IB-200-R1280T-04-en-fr-es-de-it-V1.2-1_SJozCPy4.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your speakers do not support headphones in any way. There is no output available, apart from the second speaker. There is no way to "make it work". You need to unplug the speakers, and plug your headphones into the source system (not your R1280T).

Instead, go and buy something like this:

- [This](https://www.amazon.com.au/Plugable-Headphone-Microphone-Aluminium-Compatibility/dp/B00NMXY2MO/)
- [OR this](https://www.jaycar.com.au/usb2-0-to-3-5mm-audio-converter/p/XC4953)

This will add a second audio jack to your PC, and you can use Windows to control which output device to use.

If you plan to plug in a headset (with a built-in microphone), then [this](https://www.cablesonline.com.au/usb-external-sound-card-4-pole-3-5mm-trrs-audio) would be better.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Linux. Can I control these dual plugs from linux? Also, notice that muliple answers are not allowd on SE. So please merge or remove the other answer.

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu), and you can most certainly control which output your PC uses. There is always a small issue that the usb audio device is not compatible with Linux drivers, but these are pretty standard devices, so the risk is low.